# Manually passing a view's onTouchEvent to it's parent

Tags: android

From a child view's onTouchEvent (say a TextView that is within a ListView), I was wondering what method to call if I wanted to manually forward this event to its parent.

I know I can simply call super.onTouchEvent() from the TextView's override, but I want to call the parent view manually.

I've been looking at the source, and didn't see any call to the effect of

```
parent.onTouchEvent(e)
```

and so was wondering how this is done ?

I'm thinking maybe there is a viewTreeObserver at play here, but not too sure.

Thank you.

Comment: in the child on touch event can you not return false and then the touch is automatically passed up the view tree hierarchy to the ontouch of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the android api:

> public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) Added in API level 1
>
> Implement this method to handle touch screen motion events. Parameters
>   event     The motion event. Returns
>
> ```
> True if the event was handled, false otherwise.
> ```

Implement the on touch listener in the parent, and child, and in the child, if you want the event passed up, just return false and the parent method will be invoked. This touch will iterate up the touch heirarchy until the touch is 'consumed'

EDIT --

To get parent try `View.getParent();`

```
TextView yourTV = (TV) findViewById(R.id.your_TV);
RelativeLayout yourRelLay = (RelativeLayout) yourTV.getParent();
yourRelLay.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
```

You could do that IN the onTouchEvent of the child to manually do it.

Comment: It is from this implementation (from my class TextView2 : TextView) where I want to call the parent's onTouchEvent() manually. So I need to know how a child view figures out who its parent is. I don't see any logic like this in the source for TextView.java or View.java http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java#mConnector).

Comment: Ok, that looks plausible. I guess I didn't try that b/c I didn't see it in the source, and 95% of the time i've called view.getParent() its null (lol), but I will give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: you have to make sure you are casting the getParent() to the correct type though that should throw an exception about bad cast rather than returning null

Comment: Yes, I just got a cast exception, but then once I got type correct, I got StackOverFlowException (heh), b/c I'm going into a TouchEvent/DispatchTouchEvent loop (which is ok I'll figure that part out)... Thanks a lot, I'm kinda embarrased I didn't just try this myself, I thought there'd be some elaborate, hidden trick involved (you know, some android-ish stuff :) Thanks !